# MasterPage doesn't display on the other pages

Tags: asp.net, background, master-pages, content-pages

I try to make new homepage of our website and its done. My masterpage can display on the home page and also on the login page as background picture and menus. But after login the portal then my masterpage menus and background pictures can't display on other pages. What should I do to display background pictures and menus?

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="no-js ie9 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <title>Bootstrap Templates</title>
    <!-- ============ Google fonts ============ -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond' rel='stylesheet'
        type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,300,800'
        rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <!-- ============ Add custom CSS here ============ -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>


<form runat =server >

    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.backstretch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        'use strict';

        /* ========================== */
        /* ::::::: Backstrech ::::::: */
        /* ========================== */
        // You may also attach Backstretch to a block-level element
        $.backstretch(
        [
            "img/44.jpg",
            "img/colorful.jpg",
            "img/34.jpg",
            "img/images.jpg"
        ],

        {
            duration: 4500,
            fade: 1500
        }
    );
    </script>
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">                     

                <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
                          </asp:LoginView>  <asp:LoginStatus  class="navbar-brand" ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Large"  ForeColor = "White"/>

            </div>              

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li><a href="/">Ana Sayfa</a> </li>                     

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Personel Islemleri <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: #33CCFF">
            <li><a href="personel/welcome.aspx">Kisisel Bilgiler</a></li>
            <li><a href="personel/hcmt37.aspx">Bordro</a></li>
            <li><a href="personel/een114.aspx">Netting</a></li>
            <li><a href="personel/expenses.aspx">Harcama Beyani</a></li>
            <li><a href="personel/travels.aspx">Seyahat</a></li>
            <li><a href="personel/missions.aspx">Gorev</a></li>
            <li><a href="personel/maints.aspx">Servis Talebi</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Amir Islemleri <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: #FF99CC">
            <li><a href="amir/leaves.aspx">Izin Onaylari</a></li>
            <li><a href="amir/expenses.aspx">Harcama Onaylari</a></li>
            <li><a href="amir/travels.aspx">Seyahat Onaylari</a></li>
            <li><a href="personel/expenses.aspx">Gorev Onaylari</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/ias/PASSW.aspx">Parola Degistir</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">     

    <table>   

        <tr>
     <td style="height: 1px; background-color: Black">
                <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" BackColor="Black" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2"
                    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="White" Height="24px" Orientation="Horizontal"
                    StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" Width="864px" Visible="False">
                    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="Black" />
                    <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="1px" BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" />
                    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" />
                    <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="Black" />
                    <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" />
                    <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" />
                    <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" />
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/memberpages/welcome.aspx" Text="Ana Sayfa" Value="Ana Sayfa">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/memberpages/hcmt37.aspx" Text="Bordro" Value="Bordro"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/memberpages/een114.aspx" Text="Netting" Value="Netting">
                        </asp:MenuItem>

                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Onaylar" Value="Onaylar">
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Izin" Value="Izin" NavigateUrl="~/authpages/leaves.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="Harcama" Value="Harcama" NavigateUrl="~/authpages/expenses.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="Seyahat" Value="Seyahat" NavigateUrl="~/authpages/travels.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="G&#246;rev" Value="G&#246;rev" NavigateUrl="~/authpages/missions.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>

                        </asp:MenuItem>

                          <asp:MenuItem Text="Talepler" Value="Talepler">
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Izin" Value="Izin" NavigateUrl="~/memberpages/leaves.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="Harcama Beyani" Value="Harcama" NavigateUrl="~/memberpages/expenses.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="Seyahat" Value="Seyahat" NavigateUrl="~/memberpages/travels.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="G&#246;rev" Value="G&#246;rev" NavigateUrl="~/memberpages/missions.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>

                        </asp:MenuItem>                          

<asp:MenuItem Text="Sifre Degistir" Value="Sifre Degistir" NavigateUrl="~/ias/PASSW.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>

                    </Items>
                    <StaticMenuStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White"  />
                </asp:Menu>
            </td>  

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 891px; height: 96px" valign="top">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </td>

        </tr>
        </table>

</div>
      <div id="masterpageContent" class="footer">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footerContent">
        <div class="footerbrd">
        </div>
        <p class="clear">
        </p>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="c1 flef">
                2010 Copyright Bilgi Islem
            </div>

            <p class="clear">
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>  

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With no code I bet anyone that tries to help can just try to guess something. Please, read this links and edit your question, so people can help you more easily. http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There are plenty of resources on the web that can help you..

Comment: I'm really sorry about that I forgot to paste the code :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question, but did you modify all the other pages to make them use the Master Page?. Adding a Master Page to the project does not mean that all existing pages suddenly start using it.

A .aspx page that uses a Master page should look like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebFormWithMasterPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestOmgeving.WebFormWithMasterPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <!-- all page content goes here -->

</asp:Content>
```